# Wrapping a Using Block inside of another Using Block - is it overkill?

Tags: c#, using-statement

I have a section of code in my project where I an wrapping a Using Block Inside of Another Using Block, I am wondering is this a good practice or just overkill (Please note I understand that this is a very simplistic snippet of code, it was used for illustration purposes only):

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();

                string cmdStr = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REGISTRATION WHERE UserName ='" + this.TextBoxUN.Text + "' ";
                using (SqlCommand selectUser = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, cn))
                {
                    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(selectUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

                    if (temp == 0)
                    {
                        string insCmd = "Insert INTO REGISTRATION (UserName, Password, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country)";
                        using (SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, cn))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", this.TextBoxUN.Text);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", this.TextBoxPass.Text);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", this.TextBoxEA.Text);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", this.TextBoxFN.Text);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", this.DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());

                                insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Response.Write(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("User already Exists in Database");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `using` for everything implementing `IDisposable` and dispose it as fast as possible.

Comment: Slightly tangential to the question, but you can reduce the clutter of nested using blocks by extracting the inner chunk of code as a separate private method.  This way the logic is not so deeply nested that it's hard to read, but you still have the correct outer 'using' blocks for disposal of resources.

Comment: @DanBryant Thanks, I actually have a Library Class where I handle all of this "Low Level" but to make my post easier to read and understand I went this route.

Comment: Just a quick comment - the exception catching is a bad idea. You should remove them from your code unless you've got them in purely for debugging and you plan to remove them later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Good practice. Dispose of stuff in the smallest scope possible, otherwise you're leaving it to GC to do quite some time later.

Comment: Great, I didn't think it would hurt.

Comment: The GC never disposes objects. It just frees memory. You must explicitly dispose your objects either directly or with finalizers yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can nest `using` statements.  Each `using` statement only applies to one object, so if several require disposal, use several `using` statements.

Additionally, you could reduce the nesting by closing the first command before opening the second.

```
int temp;
using (SqlCommand selectUser = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, cn))
{
    temp = Convert.ToInt32(selectUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
}
if (temp == 0)
{
    string insCmd = ...;
    using (SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, cn))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thoroughly agree that using `using` statements is a must when dealing with nested disposable objects.

However, I would suggest a further change to the code. To help make your code readable, testable and maintainable, it is a good idea to use function composition. Here's how I would change the main body of the code:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    if (checkUserExists(cn, this.TextBoxUN.Text))
    {
        Response.Write("User already Exists in Database");
    }
    else
    {
        addUser(cn, this.TextBoxUN.Text, this.TextBoxPass.Text, this.TextBoxEA.Text, this.TextBoxFN.Text, this.DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

This code is more compact and easier to reason about what is going on.

Prior to this code you need to define the `checkUserExists` and `addUser` lamdbas, like so:

```
Func<SqlConnection, string, bool> checkUserExists = (cn, un) =>
{
    var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REGISTRATION WHERE UserName = @UserName";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", un);
        return Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) != 0;
    }
};

Action<SqlConnection, string, string, string, string, string> addUser = (cn, un, pw, e, fn, c) =>
{
    string query = "Insert INTO REGISTRATION (UserName, Password, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country)";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", un);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pw);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", e);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", fn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", c);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
};
```

Each of these is also very straightforward and their intent is clear and easy to reason about.

Because they are lambdas they don't clog up your classes with unnecessary methods - it's all contained within the one method. Nice, neat & tidy.

Of course they all use `using` statements.

Hope this helps.